# Update one column from table and insert new rows. sqlite, java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-update, sql-insert

I have some problems to modify data from a table. 
I need to update an entire column from a specific table and if there's no sufficient rows I need to insert more.

More exactly, the user will be able to modify data from interface, in a text area that contains current data from db. 
I put all the text in a list, each line representing an element of the list.

In a certain column, I must go through each row and modify it with a list item.  If there are more lines in the text area than number of rows in that table, I need to insert new ones, which will contain the remaining items from the list.

I would be grateful if someone could give me some help.
Thanks!

```js
 @FXML
    public void modify() throws SQLException {

        String col= selectNorme.getValue().toString();
        String text=texta.getText();

        List<String>  l1notes= new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( text.split("\r\n|\r|\n")  ));

        Statement stmt=null;

        String client = this.clientCombobox.getValue().toString();
        String tab1Client= client+ "_" +this.selectLang1.getValue().toString();

        String query="SELECT * FROM "+tab1Client+" WHERE ["+ selectNorme.getValue().toString()+ "]= "+col+"";
        String sqlUpdate1= "UPDATE  ["+tab1Client+"] SET ["+ this.selectNorme.getValue().toString() +"] = ?";

        try {
            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement modif=conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate1);
            int i=0;

            if (rss.next()) {

                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rss = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                stmt.executeUpdate(sqlUpdate1);
                modif.setString(1, l1notes.get(i));
                i++;
                modif.execute();
            }
            else {
                
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ["+this.clientCombobox.getValue().toString()+"_"+this.selectLang1.getValue().toString()+"] (["+ this.selectNorme.getValue().toString() +"]) values (?)" );
             


                for (int row=i; row< l1notes.size(); row++)
                {

                    pstmt.setString(1, l1notes.get(row));
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                }

            }
        }
        finally {

            try {
         
                if (conn !=null)
                    conn.close();
                }
            catch (SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: show us some code... currently we cannot help you

Comment: Provide your attempts, please...

Comment: @StefanBeik i have added something that i tried

Comment: @deHaar i added what i tried

Comment: I think you will be in need of an additional SQL statement that inserts new rows. You basically check the list, update every entry that exists in the database and insert the remaining entries.